# Docusign Connect setting missing Custom Object, which was there before

Tags: docusign

We are using Docusign AppExchange installed in one of our sandbox and using this in a custom Object and sending doc for signature using standard **Send for signature** button (no Custom code for now).
Now when sending Doc for signature its displaying an error at Salesofrce UI like below.
Error on Salesforce UI ( we are not using wsdl, its standard Appexchange managed package code).

> Please contact DocuSign Support: https://support.docusign.com/. Error:
>   System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService
>   returned a SOAP Fault: A Mergefield value for a Tab could not be
>   retrieved. INVALID_TYPE: Rounding__c, Threshold__c from
>   CS_Application__c where id='a1cg0000001vMUk' ^ ERROR at
>   Row:1:Column:70 sObject type 'CS_Application__c' is not supported. If
>   you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c'
>   after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call
>   for the appropriate names. faultcode=soap:Client
>   faultactor=https://demo.docusign.net/api/3.0/dsapi.asmx

when going to check the Connect settings in Docsuign found that Custom object is not supported error is there and I am unable to see that custom object in Salesforce SObject picklist drop down.

- Unable to post the screenshot here. getting error from stackexchange.

Any quick help please?

Comment: This is probably better suited for Docusign support rather than in this forum

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved now.
The Salesforce Admin has made some changes in a separate Dev sandbox and pointed that sandbox to the same Docusign environment, hence the Docusign was pointing to the different Sandbox where the custom object was not created.
Returned back the settings and updated the Connection with the previous sandbox. Its working fine now.